# symfony3.4 service container in template

Tags: php, symfony, service, containers, symfony-3.4

I do have defined a service in my MainBundle/MainFunctions/ and in Controller I can call the service. How can I get the service container in SYMFONY 3.4 in a template now? Read the docs that it is not public anymore.

```
#view/template.html.php
<?php $shop_id = $this->container->get('main_functions')->getSessionShopId(); ?>
```

My config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
- { resource: "@FrontendMainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

my FrontendMainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: true
    frontend_locale.locale_listener:
        class: Frontend\MainBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
    main_functions:
        public: true
        class: "%main_functions_class.class%"
        arguments: ['@translator', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'....
```

I read the docs that it is not public anymore. But I can't get to main_functions in template. How?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Using the service locator into templates is a bad practice in my opinion, inject the `main_functions` service in your controller instead and pass just the needed vars to the templates.

Answer (score 0):

if you need some inteligence in your template, I advice you to use twig extension: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

this you will be able to call {{ yourFunction }}

this is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by MatMouth is the best way to interface with your service from the twig template. You can create functions for each method you need access in the template. Attempting to add your object as a twig variable is not a good practice unless it is just basic getters like you would use with Doctrine entities for example.

Here is some great documentation on setting up a new function and registering it in the container service:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/templating/twig_extension.html

You can also register a filter instead of a function. The difference between the two are the function syntax `someFunction(someVar)` and the filter `someVar|someFilter`. If you need to add additional arguments to your function or filter, just add the arguments to your callable.

Here's some documentation from Twig:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html

You can do cool things like make it HTML safe, inject the twig environment, etc...

Good luck and happy coding!